# What is the use for the "tools" folder in an Nx monorepo?

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

I'm looking for a little bit more insight and understanding about what the use of the "tools" folder in an Nx monorepo is for. What kind of information goes in there? I can see there is a "schematics" folder, would it be a place for my customer schematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is where common tooling would go for your org. Common uses are for schematics and lint rules, but there can be other things in here to help with automation.